# org.springframework doesn't contain CIpher

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, spring-framework-beans, key-generator

I want to import cipher from org.springframework dependency. I have imported it like below,

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.Cipher;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.SecretKey;
```

but there's an error throwing saying that,

```
Error:(25,63) java: package org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils does not exist
```

Then I tried

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Cipher;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.SecretKey;
```

I still get the below error,

```
Error:(25,51) java: cannot find symbol
```

I want cipher to use encryption and decryption of my otp and expiry date. How can I import cipher from org.springframework

Answer (score 2):

Class `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils` doesn't contain inner class `Cipher` and package `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt` doesn't contain class `Cipher` too.

Class `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils` [use](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f1db7167cbff8cab5baa7a2c2d5a38d746c9f676/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/CipherUtils.java#L26) the `javax.crypto.Cipher` class and You must use this class too.

Comment: Please provide additional explanation.

Comment: Okay, I added the explanation

Answer (score 1):

> Error:(25,63) java: package org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils does not exist

You receive this error because CipherUtils is a class.

Use `import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils;` if you want to use this class.

> Error:(25,51) java: cannot find symbol

You receive this error because you Cipher doesn't exist here

`import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Cipher;`.

Use `import javax.crypto.Cipher;`